# jQuery - Remove Each Element

Tags: jquery

Using javascript, I need to remove all matching elements with a single event.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#target").blur(function(){
           name = $(this).val();

              for (i = 1; i < name; i++) {
                $("#myspan").clone()
                            .attr({"id":"cloned"})
                            .appendTo("#myspan")
               }
      });

      $("#target").click(function(){
          $("#cloned").remove();
      });
});
```

As it stands now I have to click the target box multiple times to get all of the clones to remove.
Im sure its as simple as adding an each but I've worked on this all day and can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: ID's should be unique - the selector will grab the first one only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class instead.  id's must be unique in the document.  classes can be on as many objects as you want.  So, if you want a query to return multiple items, the query can't be for an id as that will only ever return one item.  Here's a way to use a class name instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#target").blur(function(){
           name = $(this).val();

              for (i = 1; i < name; i++) {
                $("#myspan").clone()
                            .addClass("cloned")
                            .removeAttr("id")
                            .appendTo("#myspan")
               }
      });

      $("#target").click(function(){
          $(".cloned").remove();
      });
});
```

Changes:

1. Call `.addClass("cloned")` to add the desired class name
2. Add `.removeAttr("id")` to remove the duplicate id after cloning
3. Change the removal query to `$(".cloned").remove();`